# Error during DNS configuration Google AppEngine / OVH

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, ovh

I bought a domain name on OVH and I am trying to set it with my flask application hosted on an GCP AppEngine.

I registered the DNS but I have this error message :

The certificat ID is not generated by Google whereas I added each type A and AAAA on my OVH configuration.
[image]

I had this error message for the CNAME : "the subdomain already uses a DNS record. You cannot register a CNAME field due to an incompatibility. Delete existing records for this subdomain, so you can add a CNAME-like one"

[image]

Comment: There is an \[official documentation\](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/7037341?hl=en) on how to fix conflicting record errors, going through this might help you in resolving the error.<br>

Comment: Have you checked this documentation on [mapping custom domain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains)? This includes prerequisites and steps that are needed in using custom domains for your app.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check the documentation on [mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains).

- Check first if your account has the [App Engine Admin role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#appengine.appAdmin)(`roles/appengine.appAdmin`) or a custom role that contains the `appengine.applications.get` permission.
- If you use [Cloud Load Balancing and serverless NEGS](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) to route traffic to your App Engine app, we recommend that you map your custom domain to the load balancer instead of directly to your app, and use SSL certificates that are created for the load balancer. Check the links below for more information:

  - [Using Google-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs)
  - [Using self-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs)
  - [SSL policies](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-policies-concepts)
- Go to [Custom Domains page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains) then add the custom domain.
- Make sure to use the naked domain such as `example.com` then click on **Verify** if it hasn't been verified yet.

If the aforementioned steps didn't you may check @KranthiveerDontineni's comments on [fixing conflicting records errors](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/7037341?hl=en) for Google Domains.